# How do I import python class from a module located within file directory named '@file_directory' or directory with special characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm trying to import a class from a module named `my_classes.py`. Problem is, it's located within a directory called *@file_directory*.

So the structure is, I have main.py at the top of the project directory, and also a directory called *lib* at the same level. Within 'lib' there is subdirectory named '@file_directory' and within it a module 'my_classes' as shown below.

```
-> main.py
-> /lib
   -> lib_other_files.py
   -> /@file_directory
      -> my_classes.py
```

What I can usually do is

```
from lib.@file_directory.myclasses import cust_class
```

But because the `@` symbol is a wrapper symbol, it prevents me from importing files from '@file_directory'. The simple soultion is of course, just change the directory name but I want to keep the file name/don't have the rights to change it in the project. Is there a way to use like a escpae character to import module from a directory with special characters?

Comment: `@file_directory` is not a valid module name; you *should* change the directory name.

Comment: @chepner changing the directory name would be the most ideal situation but he mentioned he has no permissions to change it

Comment: I've aware of what he mentioned. I'm claiming that using such a directory name is virtually a bug, and should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: [use the `__import__()` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__). This is essentially removing the overhead of the normal `import` command, but it allows you more flexibility in package-naming because it just takes a string as an argument - and that string can escape the otherwise-invalid characters.

So, this code *should* work:

```
_temp = __import__("lib.@file_directory.myclasses", globals(), locals(), ['cust_class'], 0)
cust_class = _temp.cust_class
```

---

Edit: The python standard library recommends using [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) instead. The same code would look like this in that:

```
import importlib
cust_class = importlib.import_module("lib.@file_directory.myclasses", "cust_class")
```

Comment: This *does* work, but the doc says: `__import__` should be avoided, better to use `importlib.import_module()` to programmatically import a module.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can not import modules with characters like the '@' symbol... however, using execfile may be an appropriate workaround for you.

**Tested with Python 2.7.5**

***my_classes.py example code:***

```
def printMe():
    print "foo from my_classes"
```

***main.py example code:***

```
execfile("./lib/@file_directory/my_classes.py")
printMe()
```

*Executing main.py prints out:*

```
>>python main.py
foo from my_classes
```

Whats happening is **main.py** will run the **my_classes.py** file and now you can directly reference functions or any relevant code from my_classes.py.

**Python 3.X Equivalent**

I dont have python 3 installed but they did remove execfile.. the alternative for execfile would be:

```
exec(open("./lib/@file_directory/my_classes.py").read())
```

Hope this helps you accomplish your needs.